# category vs tag

Tags: tags, blogs, categories

What are the main differences between setting a Category and applying a Tag (in blog posting)? 
Is there a "silver-bullet" question for splitting Categories and Tags?

In my current approach there is a mess of tags and categories and I think this is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Categories are hierarchical, i.e. they can have subcategories - if they don't, there's not much difference from tags.
The best functionality is in using categories and tags for completely separate purposes, so that every tag can span over several categories. This way, navigation through your site becomes much more intuitive.